# Pattern to deduce class template arguments from static member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

### My situation

I have two classes, supplied by an external libary not under my control, e.g. their interface is fixed for me.

The first one is a templated 2-D container type, that allows me to manipulate the content held through member functions as well as through raw pointer.
The second one is a class containing a bunch of static member functions that abstract some heavily SIMD-optimized vector operations. Most of them are overloaded to take different datatypes, however they all share a same interface like

```
VecOperations::op (Type* dest, const Type* src, /* a variable number of operation specific arguments */, int len)
```

### What I want to achieve:

I want to iterate over the first dimension of my 2D container and apply a vector operation to each vector in the second iteration in place. Therefore I want to replace e.g.

```
auto** ptrs = conatiner.getArrayOfRawPointers();
for (int i = 0; i < container.getXDim(); ++i)
    VecOperations::foo (ptrs[i], ptrs[i], arg1, arg2, arg3, container.getYDim());
```

ideally by something like this (pseudocode)

```
forAllElements<VecOperations::foo> (container, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

This should work for all kind of types stored in my container which are supported by the vector operations classes well as for all numbers of vector operation specific args. To my knowledge writing something like `forAllElements` above is not possible.

### My current solution:

I came up with this instead:

```
template <typename ElemType, typename ...Args>
struct ForAllElemements
{
    template <void(*op)(ElemType*, const ElemType*, Args..., int)>
    static void call (Container<ElemType>& buffer, Args... args)
    {
        auto xDim = container.getXDim();
        auto yDim = container.getYDim();
        auto** ptrs = conatiner.getArrayOfRawPointers();

        for (int i = 0; i < xDim; ++i)
            op (ptrs[i], const_cast<const ElemType*>(ptrs[i]), args..., yDim);
    }
};
```

This can be used like

```
// using a Container<float> and VecOperations::foo (float*, const float*, float, int, float, int)

ForAllElemements<float, float, int, float>::call<VecOperations::foo> (container, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

While in C++17 deducing class template arguments from the constructor works, deducing it from a static function call does not work to my knowledge. From my understanding, this is simply not defined, technically I don't see any reason why

```
ForAllElemements::call<VecOperations::foo> (container, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

should be impossible, as all template types can be deduced from the parameters passed to the static function.

So I'm asking you, is there any super clever workaround or pattern I'm not aware of that would make something like this possible with C++17 or also with the later standards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class template argument deduction happens only based on an initializer for a class object. Here you don't even want an object of the class type, just to use static member functions.

But backing up, maybe a plain function template can work:

```
// C++20 will define std::type_identity_t; or just define your own:
template <typename T>
struct type_identity { using type = T; };
template <typename T>
using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;

template <typename ...Args, typename ElemType>
void forAllElements(
    Container<ElemType> &c,
    void (*op)(ElemType*, const ElemType*, type_identity_t<Args>..., int), 
    Args...);
```

The function pointer does need to be a function argument here instead of a template argument. This works with plain `Args...` in the function pointer signature instead of `type_identity_t<Args>...` if the function is overloaded, but when the function is NOT overloaded, compilers might require the `type_identity_t`, presumably to make sure `Args` is in a non-deduced context there. (I think there's an unclear requirement in the Standard causing some different results...)

Note `Args` can only be deduced from the arguments to `forAllElements` and not from the function type, and the function type needs to be an exact match. So if you allow those types to be deduced, you'll need to be careful about the exact types of the expressions you pass in. Cast them if necessary. If using literals as constant values, you can use forms like `1.0f` to get a `float` type, etc. Or, you can specify the argument types like `forAllElements<float, int, float>`, which is why I put `...Args` before `ElemType` in the template (though now `ElemType` can never be explicitly given and must be deduced from the container argument).

Comment: Thank you for that answer. This type_identity helper struct solution was the part I didn't know to be possible... Will definitively add that to my personal collection of utilities and use it in other places as well to simplify some variadic template stuff